# SQLite database error delete query

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, sql-delete

I am developing a gym membership program on visual studio using C# and sqlite. On every employee-log in attempt, I want the program to check for expired customers where ExpiryDate(Attribute in the table Customer) is less than today's date. this is the piece of code I used:

```
string sql2 = "delete from Customer where ExpiryDate<' " + DateTime.Today + " ' ";
SQLiteCommand command2 = new SQLiteCommand(sql2, m_dbConnection);
command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Are you sure you really want to delete your customers? Does that mean that if they're one minute late with payment, they have to register for a new membership? :)

Answer (score 3):

Use a parameterized query and your problems in converting a date to a string will evaporate

```
 string sql2 = "delete from Customer where ExpiryDate < @td"; 
 SQLiteCommand command2 = new SQLiteCommand(sql2, m_dbConnection); 
 command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@td", DateTime.Today);
 command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Of course this is also the recommended way to avoid Sql Injections but in this case is not your main concern.

By the way, I agree with comments in your question above. Probably it is better to allow a bit of flexibility in the calculation of the deadlines. For example you could add a configuration option that set the maximum number of days allowed after the deadline and add it to the DateTime.Today value.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use SQLite built-in functions?

```
delete from Customer where ExpiryDate<DATE('NOW')
```

Aren't you missing something like

```
delete from Customer where ExpiryDate<DATE('NOW') AND Costumer_id=?
```